# Installing .deb packages with Ubuntu Software

Tags: 16.04, software-center, deb

I cannot seem to install any downloaded `.deb` package by clicking on it (I am on Ubuntu 16.04):

- they open with the "Ubuntu Software" GUI, with a button "Install";
- clicking on this button seems to do *something* (as in, a progress-bar appears), but the software is not installed afterwards.

I can install them from the console using `sudo apt install /path/to/foo.deb`, but I would like to know why the graphical way of doing things doesn't work.

Note: I know I can also install `gdebi` to install `.deb` packages, but that's not really the point of my question :)

Comment: Uhm, `apt install` does not take filenames as argument. You have to use `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`, after which you likely have to run `sudo apt install -f` to fix missing dependencies.

Comment: @ByteCommander Have you tried it? It might just be an alias of `dpkg -i`, but `apt install ./foo.deb` works.

Comment: @Sheljohn Oh, indeed. I did try it, but with implicit relative paths only (i.e. `apt install Downloads/test.deb`). It works with explicit relative paths (`./Downloads/test.deb`) or absolute paths (`/home/username/Downloads/test.deb`) though. Learned something today. Unfortunately Bash-autocomplete doesn't pick up filenames there.